# Teensy / Arduino code Serial.begin(True); How does this set the baud rate?

Tags: timer, arduino, interrupt

From https://github.com/loglow/IntervalTimer/blob/master/examples/Basic/Basic.ino

For [Teensy 3.1 Timer.](https://github.com/loglow/IntervalTimer/)

In void setup():

```
#include "IntervalTimer.h"

volatile bool printNow = true;
volatile uint32_t timerCounter0;
volatile uint32_t timerCounter1;
volatile uint32_t timerCounter2;

void printTimerCounters() {
  Serial.print("timer0: ");
  Serial.print(timerCounter0);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print("timer1: ");
  Serial.print(timerCounter1);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print("timer2: ");
  Serial.print(timerCounter2);
  Serial.print("\n\r");
  printNow = false;
}

void timerCallback0() {
  timerCounter0++;
}

void timerCallback1() {
  timerCounter1++;
  timerCounter0 = 0;
}

void timerCallback2() {
  timerCounter2++;
  printNow = true;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(true);
  delay(500);
  IntervalTimer timer0;
  IntervalTimer timer1;
  IntervalTimer timer2;
  timer0.begin(timerCallback0, 500); // 2 kHz
  timer1.begin(timerCallback1, 5000000); // 5 seconds
  timer2.begin(timerCallback2, 1000000); // 1 second
}

void loop() {
  if (printNow) printTimerCounters();
```

I am used to `Serial.begin(Number_here);`

But in the code it has `Serial.begin(true);`

Comment: Either the author of this code uses a different library, or he hasn't read the documentation. Since there's no overload of `begin()` that takes a `bool`, only one that takes a `long`, your `bool` is converted to a `long` (it will become 1), so this sets the baud rate to 1 baud (1 bit per second).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Teensy uses the USB buffer to transmit data as fast as the protocol will allow. His library includes IntervalTimer.cpp and IntervalTimer.h, which need to be placed into the teensy3 core library in the arduino main directory, and then the arduino work environment needs to be restarted for the changes to take place.

The relevant information was taken from http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_serial.html#txbuffer and https://github.com/loglow/IntervalTimer .

Comment: Yes. Thanks for this. I didn't catch the one line held within the links that you included. So basically Serial.begin() gets automagically ignored.